# how can i get other application preference screen for ours

Tags: android

today is not my day i am stuck with this problem

how can i access other application preference screen from my application by specifying in the preference screen layout using intent or something

what is the better or correct way to do so??????

thanks in advance

regards,
kariyachan

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you are not able to access other applications from your own. That would have huge security implications. Why do you need access to another application anyway?

Applications are separated for a reason. If I download two separate apps that do two separate things, I don't want one of them messing with the other in any way (settings, cache, saved files, database, etc).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i asked just because of curiosity i read from a site that "preference hierarchies can include Preference Screens from other applications — including system Preference Screens." how can i do that any idea ??